# An example of almost sure finite random time S such that $W_t=B_{S+t}-B_S$ is not a brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, markov-process

Let $\{B_t,\mathcal{F}_t,t \geq 0\}$ be a standard one dimensional Brownian motion. Give an example of a random time $S$ with $P[0\leq S< \infty]=1$ such that with $W_t:=B_{S+t}-B_S$, the process $W=\{W_t, \mathcal{F}^w_t;t\geq0\}$ is not a brownian motion.

How could I go about constructing such an example. I have no idea of how to proceed.
I tried to invent an almost sure finite random time using the law of large numbers for Brownian motion
$T_{\epsilon}=\{\sup_{s \geq0}: B_s\geq s\epsilon\}$
but I am not sure on how to handle the object $B_{T_{\epsilon}+t}-B_{T_{\epsilon}}$.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $S = \inf \{s\ge 0:B_{s+1}-B_s\ge 0\}$. Since $W_1\ge0$ almost surely, $W_t$ cannot be a Brownian motion.

Comment: How do you come up with such nice examples?

Comment: Amazing! Neat example.

Comment: It helped to know a related result: if $S$ is a "stopping time," then $W_t$ is a Brownian motion. A stopping time is a random time such that once it happens, you will know it has happened. My $S$ is not a stopping time because in order to know $S$ has occurred, you have to look into the future at $B_{S+1}$.

Comment: [cont] Then I realized if you choose $S$ to be any time which depends on the future, then you can force the process after $S$ to have certain properties. @user3503589

Comment: Another canonical example is $S=\sup\{s\leqslant1:B_s=0\}$.

Comment: @Did Why isn't $W_{t}$ a Brownian motion ?

Comment: @XXX It's not a BM because the increments would be positive random variables and cannot be normally distributed